# How to add a parameter to element style in Jinja macro?

Tags: python, html, css, jinja2

I'd like to pass a `background-image` as a parameter in Jinja macro. I got something working without parameterised like this:

```
{% macro pm_card() %}
    <div style="background-image: url(../static/images/hm_bg.jpg)" class='card-img-top'></div>
{% endmacro %}
```

I can't seem to do this:

```
{% macro pm_card(bg) %}
    <div style="background-image: {{bg}}" class='card-img-top'></div>
{% endmacro %}
```

then pass `bg` this way:

```
{{pm_card('../static/images/hm_portrait.jpg')}}
```

How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay this worked:

```
{% macro pm_card() %}
    <div style="background-image: url({{bg}})"></div>
{% endmacro %}
```

and use it like this:

```
{{pm_card('../static/images/hm_portrait.jpg')}}
```

Comment: Thank God for people that answer their own questions if and when they find a solution!!